# Appium Invalid Session exception

Tags: appium, appium-android, python-appium

I am working on automating testcases for a mobile application. Things were working fine but now suddenly I am getting the following exception

```
Stacktrace:io.appium.uiautomator2.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: The session identified by dc719686-277b-422f-81be-fe156d72ea29 is not known
```

When I run the script, The application gets opened in the mobile and the webdriver is returned. But when I use that webdriver for anything else, I am getting this exception. At first, I got the socket hangup error which I fixed using the systemPort capability. Any idea why it's happening and what's the way out of this. Following is the whole log.

````
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSessionIdException: Message: The session identified by 25030467-b3ad-4f74-a6ce-10f8ffab97c3 is not known
Stacktrace:
io.appium.uiautomator2.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: The session identified by 25030467-b3ad-4f74-a6ce-10f8ffab97c3 is not known
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.request.SafeRequestHandler.handle(SafeRequestHandler.java:54)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleRequest(AppiumServlet.java:266)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleHttpRequest(AppiumServlet.java:260)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.http.ServerHandler.channelRead(ServerHandler.java:68)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:435)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:250)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:611)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:552)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:466)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:438)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)```
````

Answer (score 2):

Switch off and restart the device and check if it is working.

I had the same issue and solved by this method